# How to specify table relationships in SQLAlchemy with multi-level/multiple joins?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to define a relationship between two tables whose relations are indirect (i.e. through two other tables).

The results I'm looking for can be fetched with this query:

```
(db.session.query(Telnum)
           .filter(Account.customer==customer)
           .filter(Account.account_id == Subscription.account_id)
           .filter(Telnum.sub_id == Subscription.id)
           .order_by(Telnum.telnum)
           .all()
)
```

where `customer` is a Customer object.

I'm struggling to figure out how this would be defined as a relationship, similar to the `Customer.invoices` relationship. An idea I had was something like this:

```
telnums = db.relationship('Telnum',
                       primaryjoin="and_(Account.user_id==Customer.id, "
                       "Account.account_id == Subscription.account_id, " 
                       "Telnum.sub_id == Subscription.id)", 
                       backref='customer')
```

As evident by this post, that does not work. The error message it produces is this: 
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any simple equality expressions involving locally mapped foreign key columns for primary join condition 'accounts.user_id = customers.id AND accounts.account_id = subscriptions.account_id AND pstn_numbers.sub_id = subscriptions.id' on relationship Customer.telnums.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation. To allow comparison operators other than '==', the relationship can be marked as viewonly=True.`

Could anyone hint me in the right direction?

I have the following table structure (simplified, all irrelevant columns removed apart from one for each table):

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    identification_num = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    invoices = db.relationship('Invoice', backref='customer')
    accounts = db.relationship('Account', backref='customer')

def __init__(self):
    pass

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Customer %r>' % (self.name)

class Invoice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'invoices'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customers.id'))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    accounts = db.relationship('Account', backref='invoice')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Invoice %r>' % (self.id)

class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    invoice_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('invoices.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customers.id'))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    subscriptions = db.relationship('Subscription', backref='account')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Account %r>' % (self.account_id)

class Subscription(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subscriptions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.account_id'))
    sub_active = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    telnums = db.relationship('Telnum', backref='subscription')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Subscription %r>' % (self.id)

class Telnum(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pstn_numbers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sub_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subscriptions.id'))
    telnum = db.Column(db.String(64))
    holder = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Telnum %r>' % (self.telnum)
```

Comment: **Q1:** Are you trying to get `Telnums` from a `Customer`? **Q2:** Do you really need a relationship, or would a query (or query-enabled property) suffice?

Comment: @van **A1:** Yes, I'm trying to get all the Telnums belonging to a customer. The Customer can have many Accounts, which can have many Subscriptions, which then can have many Telnums.  
**A2:** I don't really need the relationship, I guess. I considered creating a function within Customer which would perform a query and return the data, but I thought that a relationship would probably be the "correct" and clean way to go. I'm also trying to get a better grasp of SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, I would not define an *indirect* relationship as a `relationship`, because you risk these *indirect* relationships becoming out-of-sync when you make modifications. You might work-around some of these limitations by specifying the [`viewonly=False`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.viewonly) parameter for a `relationship`.

A simpler, less risky, and more straight-forward solution would be to use a query (or query-enabled property) in case you would like to reload data from the database, and use python list comprehensions to get the sub-sub-children of the relationship tree:

```
class Customer(Base):
    # ...

    @property
    def telnums_qry(self):
        sess = Session.object_session(self)
        return (sess.query(Telnum)
                .join(Subscription)
                .join(Account)
                .filter(Account.user_id == self.id)
                ).all()


    @property
    def telnums_mem(self):
        return [tel
                for acc in self.accounts
                for sub in acc.subscriptions
                for tel in sub.telnums
                ]


class Telnum(Base):
    # ...

    @property
    def customer(self):
        return (self.subscription
                and self.subscription.account
                and self.subscription.account.customer
                )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wound up using telnums_qry in favor of telnums_mem as it it a little bit faster.
Thanks also for cleaning up the query by using joins -- learned a lot seeing how you use pre-existing/pre-defined relations to make the query more succint.

Comment: Great. Using query will issue a query every time though, while using a `session (UnitOfWork)` will load objects just once, then it is pure python which should be faster as no IO (db call) is involved. Basically, depends on the use case. You can also configure relationships to be eagerly loaded in case your UseCase needs them anyways.

Comment: Good to know. This particular use case will likely just use the data once, but I appreciate the info for potential future use cases. I don't have a high enough reputation to vote up your answer. Sorry :(

Comment: @van i'm a little confused. You say that using a session will load objects just once, and a query will hit the database every time. However, your query has the session, and the list comprehension does not. If one just uses a list comprehension, when, if ever, does it query the database a second time? Also, what is the point of "@property" other than having to add () to call the class method?

Comment: @Chockomonkey: answers to some of your questions is "it depends". The `telnums_qry` will execute one query which will fetch all sub-sub-children, so will hit the database only once (and will do it again every time the property is accessed).

`telnums_mem` will basically navigate children, sub-children and sub-sub-children "on demand". If those all are loaded already in memory (cached in the session), no further DB queries will be made. But if those have not been loaded, each navigation will trigger SA to load children by executing a `SELECT` statement.